# getSelectedRows in Angular UI grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I select a row by

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(rowIndex)
```

and then I want to return a selected row by

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows()
```

I got 0 (zero) rows. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: no one knows until you share more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is `rowIndex` but `selectRow()` receives object and not integer.

For example:  `$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0])`

Some example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NjnMb65w86L0bKmkkJp0?p=preview)

Reference: [ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection)

Comment: So, this is a hack.. :) it's working like a charm now! Thank you!